# Convert all column of dataframe to numeric with R language Scientific number

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to read a `.csv` file with R, but my data frame contains scientific numbers like 13E07.

How do I convert these into numeric in R?

```
library("data.table") 
df <- fread(header=TRUE, sep = ";" , "path/file1.csv"  , select = c("Column2", "Column3", "Column4"))
```

[image]

Comment: The default is to use "." as a decimal separator. Set `dec=","` in your `fread()` call and it should read them as numeric.

Comment: perfect MrFlick, that resolved my problem (dec=",")